# Type Error while using the make_blobs function to create two clusters of unequal sizes

Tags: python, list, svm, typeerror

I am trying to execute the following code for a classification problem with unbalanced classes. The code is from the sci-kit learn tutorial page for Support Vector Machines, but I get a 'Type Error' when I attempt to run it. [Link to page.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-unbalanced-py)

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# we create two clusters of random points
n_samples_1 = 1000
n_samples_2 = 100
centers = [[0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 2.0]]
clusters_std = [1.5, 0.5]
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=[n_samples_1, n_samples_2],
                  centers=centers,
                  cluster_std=clusters_std,
                  random_state=0, shuffle=False)

# fit the model and get the separating hyperplane
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1.0)
clf.fit(X, y)

# fit the model and get the separating hyperplane using weighted classes
wclf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight={1: 10})
wclf.fit(X, y)

# plot the samples
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, edgecolors='k')

# plot the decision functions for both classifiers
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# create grid to evaluate model
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T

# get the separating hyperplane
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins
a = ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[0], alpha=0.5, linestyles=['-'])

# get the separating hyperplane for weighted classes
Z = wclf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins for weighted classes
b = ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='r', levels=[0], alpha=0.5, linestyles=['-'])

plt.legend([a.collections[0], b.collections[0]], ["non weighted", "weighted"],
           loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-dc0e2c85c158> in <module>()
     14                   centers=centers,
     15                   cluster_std=clusters_std,
---> 16                   random_state=0, shuffle=False)
     17 
     18 # fit the model and get the separating hyperplane

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\samples_generator.py in make_blobs(n_samples, n_features, centers, cluster_std, center_box, shuffle, random_state)
    750 
    751     n_centers = centers.shape[0]
--> 752     n_samples_per_center = [int(n_samples // n_centers)] * n_centers
    753 
    754     for i in range(n_samples % n_centers):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'list' and 'int'
```

The code runs when I treat the 'n_samples' variable as an integer but I'm not sure why it fails to accept a list as an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of scikit-learn are you running?

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

I had the same error when I was on 0.19.1 but this went away with 0.20.1.

Comment: Updating the version fixed the issue. Thank you.